# Access VisualForce page with specified credentials

Tags: visualforce, controller, contact, controller-extension, standardcontroller

I want to create a VisualForce login page.Only my contacts with their username and password which is filled in the custom fields of account object should be able to redirect to next page.

Answer (score 0):

Is the next page navigation triggered from a button on the Account pagelayout?

If thats the case, you can have a java script to validate the two custom fields and then if the condition is passed then call the VF using

window.location = 'apex/YourVisualforcePage';

Hope it helps,

Thanks